GridView`s SQL Data Source update
this is the aspx GridView
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:con %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [Client_tbl].[client_fullname],[Ticket_tbl].[client_phone],[Client_tbl].[client_email],[Client_tbl].[client_company],[Client_tbl].[client_id_num],[Client_tbl].[client_tax_num],[Ticket_tbl].[ticket_category],[Ticket_tbl].[ticket_shortdetails],[Ticket_tbl].[ticket_details],[Ticket_tbl].[user_fullname],[Ticket_tbl].[user_branch],[ticket_date] FROM [Ticket_tbl] INNER JOIN [Client_tbl] ON [Ticket_tbl].[client_phone] = [Client_tbl].[client_phone] ORDER BY [Ticket_tbl].[ticket_id] DESC"></asp:SqlDataSource>
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" class="table table-bordered table-striped" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="client_fullname" HeaderText="اسم العميل" SortExpression="client_fullname" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="client_phone" HeaderText="التليفون" SortExpression="client_phone" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="client_email" HeaderText="الإيميل" SortExpression="client_email" ItemStyle-CssClass="hidden" HeaderStyle-CssClass="hidden" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="client_company" HeaderText="الشركة" SortExpression="client_company" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="client_id_num" HeaderText="رقم البطاقة" SortExpression="client_id_num" ItemStyle-CssClass="hidden" HeaderStyle-CssClass="hidden" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="client_tax_num" HeaderText="رقم التسجيل الضريبى" SortExpression="client_tax_num" ItemStyle-CssClass="hidden" HeaderStyle-CssClass="hidden" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ticket_category" HeaderText="القسم" SortExpression="ticket_category" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ticket_shortdetails" HeaderText="مختصر التفاصيل" SortExpression="ticket_shortdetails" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ticket_details" HeaderText="التفاصيل" SortExpression="ticket_details" ItemStyle-CssClass="hidden" HeaderStyle-CssClass="hidden" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="user_fullname" HeaderText="المستخدم" SortExpression="user_fullname" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="user_branch" HeaderText="الفرع" SortExpression="user_branch" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ticket_date" HeaderText="التاريخ" SortExpression="ticket_date" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

And this is the aspx.cs
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            client_fullnameTextBox2.Text = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text;
            client_phoneTextBox2.Text = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[2].Text;

            if (GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[3].Text != "&nbsp;") { client_emailTextBox2.Text = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[3].Text; }
            else { client_emailTextBox2.Text = ""; }

            if (GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[4].Text != "&nbsp;") { client_companyTextBox2.Text = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[4].Text; }
            else { client_companyTextBox2.Text = ""; }

            if (GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[5].Text != "&nbsp;") { client_id_numTextBox2.Text = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[5].Text; }
            else { client_id_numTextBox2.Text = ""; }

            if (GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[6].Text != "&nbsp;") { client_tax_numTextBox2.Text = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[6].Text; }
            else { client_tax_numTextBox2.Text = ""; }
            
            ticket_categoryDropDownList2.SelectedValue = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[7].Text;
            ticket_shortdetailsTextBox2.Text = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[8].Text;

            if (GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[9].Text != "&nbsp;") { ticket_detailsTextArea2.InnerText = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[9].Text; }
            else { ticket_detailsTextArea2.InnerText = "&nbsp;"; }
            
            mymodal.Visible = true;

        }

used GridView to display the SQL data from database, but my problem is that the SQLDataSource select all the database entries which will cause page load so much slower.
Please tell me how to create a better code to handle data display and pagination.

See tutorial Sorting, paging, and filtering data with model binding and web forms

Many Thanks, thats what i was looking after
"Deferred query execution improves the application efficiency. Instead of retrieving the entire data set, the GridView modifies the query to retrieve only the records for the current page."

How many total rows do you have? You can get away using the built in data pager, and page the GV. So, say 15 rows per page, and the total data pull (max rows) can be about 300 rows. After that, you pulling too many rows. Remember, the data pager works wonders for chopping that 300 rows into say display of about 15, and thus the response time and load should be absolute instant. However, if the data pull is going to be more then say about 300 rows, then you need to introduce SQL server paging, and that will run just as fast with 1 million rows vs 20 rows.  So, what is your max row count?

thank you for your answer, i did read that when you choose allow paging and page size for the grid view, rows will be called according to the max size of page (let`s say pagesize=10 'rows') which will help minimize the load time and the max row count wont be an issue (because it will be handled by allowpaging)
